# Delete text between 2 string (html tags)

Tags: html, regex, batch-file

I would like to delete some text from a large text file.
The main point is to find a string (html tag) and delete all text until the end of the tag.

This is what I tried to do:

```
C:\>type sample.txt | findstr /r /<tag+[^?]+<\/tag>/g
```

But ofc its not working.

Comment: and what is the html tag? Can be done easy with the windows built-in xml   parsers   but xpath is needed

Comment: The tag is <font> and </font>

Comment: you mean all font tags?

Comment: Yes, all of the font tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script (save it with `.bat` extension) accepts one argument - the html file.It will print in the console (can be redirected to file) the content of file with removed  nodes.
Not sure if you want to remove the font tag and the content in it or just the tags:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
        @echo off 



        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"  %* 
        exit /b %errorlevel% 
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */ 

var ARGS = WScript.Arguments; 
var file=ARGS.Item(0);

var FileSystemObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
//var objXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
//objXMLHTTP.open("GET", file);
//objXMLHTTP.sent();

var readFile=FileSystemObj.OpenTextFile(file,1);
var content=readFile.ReadAll();

var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
var oSelection;
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(content);

if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
   var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
   WScript.Echo("You have error " + myErr.reason);
} else {
   //WScript.Echo("Before removing <font> nodes:\n" + xmlDoc.xml + "\n");
   oSelection = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//font");
   oSelection.removeAll();
   //WScript.Echo("After removing <font> nodes:\n" + xmlDoc.xml + "\n");
   WScript.Echo(xmlDoc.xml);
}


//var doc=objXMLHTTP.responseXML;
//var tags=doc.oXMLDOMElement.getElementsByTagName("font");
//var selection=doc.selectNodes("//font")
//WScript.Echo(tags.Length);
//selection.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option similar to npocmaka's solution.  Rather than using an XML DOM which requires your HTML to be strictly valid, it uses the `htmlfile` COM object.  This method doesn't require all your tags to be closed as XML parsers do.  The drawback is that the `htmlfile` COM object does strange things to your code -- capitalizing all tag names, removing quotes from around parameters, removing XHTML-ish `<element />` self-closing slashes and so forth.  But the modified page should still render the same nevertheless.

This script will overwrite the file you wish to modify.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "htmlfile=test.html"

cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%htmlfile%"

goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    fso = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    file = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1),
    html = file.ReadAll(),
    doctype = (html.replace(/\r?\n/g,'').match(/<!doctype.*?>/i) || [''])[0];

file.Close();
DOM.write(html);

var del = DOM.getElementsByTagName('font');

for (var i=del.length; --i>-1;)
    del[i].parentNode.removeChild(del[i]);

file = fso.CreateTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), true);
file.Write((doctype ? doctype + '\n' : '') + DOM.documentElement.outerHTML);
file.Close();
DOM.close();
```